# How to Change div Position in responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is [my website](https://promo.inkgility.com/) which I am working on.

As you can see there is a sidebar in desktop mode. But when you see it in mobile mode the sidebar goes down under the content which is showing on the left side.

Now what I want in mobile view is to make sidebar appear on top, and after that the content should appear. I've tried lots of things like `position:absolute;` and `margin` but it's not working for me.

Please suggest what would be the correct way to do this task.

[jsFiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/ehozb5v9/1/)

This works for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var windowWidth = $(window).width();
//window.alert(windowWidth);
if(windowWidth<=767){
    $('.wf-span-4').insertBefore('.wf-span-8');
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: please add the relevant code to your question, or set up a working, minimal example on something like jsFiddle. This way your question remains relevant to future googlers

Comment: This is the demo of desktop view [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ehozb5v9/)
As you can see the Hi in left and bye in right Now what i want is to show bye on top and hi on bottom in the Mobile view

Comment: That's not a working demo. There is no mobile view (no @media queries). It should obviously reproduce your issue...

Comment: I have updated the code can you check now

Comment: I still see the same code (my have been caused by me editing your question at the same time :-s ) Could you try and update the link again?

Comment: Okay i have made changes again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably provide a simplified version of your code, however, here's what I've got.

You have one of two options:

1. change the structure of the site so that the order is reversed in
   the first place.
2. Use jquery to move the content below a certain
   width ex: `$('#sidebar').insertBefore('#content')`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way imo would be to put your markup in the right order to begin with. Markup is structure and should be independent of styling (as much as possible).

Then your code would look something like this

```
<section class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">Bye</div>
    <main class='content'>Hi</main> 
</section>
```

And all you would have to do is remove the floats on mobile, so the content goes back into the default flow. Something like this:

```
.content {
    width:75%;
    float:left;
}
.sidebar {
    width:25%;
    float:right
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    .content, .sidebar {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

(note that I updated your class names and markup, just so the code would be a bit better readable)

And here is your updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ehozb5v9/2/

Comment: But there is no float using in Website so that's why i was giving you the website link